# Adding logic to a dropdown box with javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript is very new to me, and so I am surprised I made it this far.  But now I am at a roadblock on how to proceed.

I have an Edit View in MVC5/C#.  There is a dropdown, where the user can update the status of the order.  I wanted to update the Stock On Hand onchange (only if the user selects 'Complete' from the dropdown) to be the original stock on hand minus the order amount.  And, I got this part working.

But now, I have realized that I need much more logic.  What if the user selects Complete by accident (and it minuses out the stock for the order), but then they suddenly realize that they selected Complete by accident, and they now change it to "processing".

How do I reverse what I just did? The first onchange event is complete and so the values are no longer the same.  I am not sure how to put it back as it was if this happens.  And it WILL happen.

Here is my jscript for the onchange dropdown, where 'Remaining' is the ID of the textbox that holds the value of OnHand minus Ordered Amount.  And "OnHand" is the element ID for what is currently on hand.  This works perfectly, but I am not sure how to add the additional logic to step back if needed.

```
  $("[name='CheckStatus']").change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == 'Complete') {
          var contents = document.getElementById('Remaining').value;
          $("#OnHand").val(contents);
     }
  });
```

Comment: I just had a brainstorm.  I am thinking . . I can add a hidden textbox on the view, with the original value of OnHand . . and then grab that if the user selects any other option in the dropdown, other than Complete . . . I will test that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I cheated. I went ahead and added a hidden field to hold the original value of what is on hand . . and then I added a second IF into my code (below), and it works just the way I wanted it to.  I assume there are much better ways to do this . . but it at least got the job done, for now.

```
  if ($(this).val() == 'Complete') {
    var contents = document.getElementById('Remaining').value;
        $("#OnHand").val(contents);                                   
    }

  if ($(this).val() !== 'Complete') { 
      var contents = document.getElementById('OrigStock').value;
         $("#OnHand").val(contents);                                    
    }
```